# Polya enumeration theorem, general form

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

In classic [Polya enumeration theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) we have group $G$ acting on $X$ in $Y^X.$ Is there some similar statement, where we have also group $H$ acting on $Y?$

My opinion is that's true, but I can't find it.

Comment: I believe if I understand your question correctly what you are refering to is the so-called **Power Group Enumeration.** I recommend the book *Graphical Enumeration* by Harary and Palmer.

Comment: Oh, yes, I've got it! Thank you!